# How to send csp(content secure policy) headers with from request

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy

Actually i have implemented csp headers on server side in apache httpd config,and it works very well,whenever i got response from server it added csp headers.
But i want to add csp headers when send request to server like form submit,get request.
Please let me know is there any way?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: i want to match the request csp headers with the server csp headers

Comment: what good will that do?

Comment: so that to be sure every request coming from the allowed csp headers of server side

Answer (score 0):

csp `headers/meta tags` are only for browser use, to limit the domains the resources can be pulled/executed from. what you are describing sounds awfully a lot like `csrf tokens` to me. take a look at this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.  i hope this helps.